# How can i pass latitude and longtitude variables to create google map preview

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created the following script and i need to pass the lat and long variables to the url in order to create a google map preview. I need to make the preview on window.open with a hybrid map, marker and define zoom.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function geoPreview(lat,long) {
var elemA = document.getElementById("lat").value;
var elemB = document.getElementById("long").value;

window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+elemA+', '+elemB+');
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful to solve your problem: http://asnsblues.blogspot.pt/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't like google maps. So here the OpenStreetmap-Solution :D

```
window.open('http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat='+elemA+'&mlon='+elemB);
```